# How can I allow users to subscribe to changes to specific files in Subversion?

Tags: svn, redmine

I'd like developers in my group to be able to subscribe to changes to specific files in our Subversion repository and receive emails when changes are made.

We're using Redmine, but I don't see any "watch" functionality for the Repository section.

Any ideas on how to implement this? I don't want to have to change some post-commit hook file each time someone wants to watch something new.